# Ext.NET DateField - formatting reversing itself

Tags: datetime, extjs, ext.net

We have a weird situation where an Ext.NET datefield is 'switching' formats if we input values in a certain style.

Specifically, if I input '01/12/09', when I blur the field, it will appear as '12/01/2009'. If I then focus the field and remove the '20' so the format reads '12/01/09' when I blur the field, it will 'switch' and show '01/12/09'.

What's odd is that we only see this behaviour on our production environment. I've done all the obvious things like checking the locale/region settings on the production box but haven't yet found anything which circumvents the behaviour.

Does anyone have any ideas on places to check next? This is based on Ext.js 3.3.1.

Many thanks,

Doug

Comment: What is the CurrentUICulture setting of the app (on the server), and have you set either the .Locale of the `<ext:ResourceManager>`, or the .CurrentUICulture on the @Page directive?

Comment: The CurrentUICulture in the web.config is 'en-GB' and we've not set it on the @Page directive. We've also not set the Locale on the resource manage, so I'll give that a go too, thanks Geoffrey

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple test I used in an attempt to recreate the problem, although was unable.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" UICulture="en-GB" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Ext.Net" namespace="Ext.Net" tagprefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:DateField ID="DateField1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Which version of Ext.NET are you using 1.0, 1.1 or 1.2?

Can you modify the sample above to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, I'm afraid the issue is a bit of a pain as I'm only seeing this on our production environment, not on my local dev version. As a result I'm going to be unlikely to be able to reproduce the issue in any sensible format. I'm afraid I'm out of the office tomorrow but will see if either the changes you mentioned yield a result on Weds, thanks again for the pointers

Comment: Hi again Geoffrey, Just as a slight update, we're using Ext.Net.dll ver 1.0.4099.29324. I will update the resource manager .Locale and let you know the effect during our next release. Thanks again for all the info

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, just a further update, we finally got around to releasing the next patch for our system with the odd date reversal issue and unfortunately the Locale side of things has not sorted it, I will keep looking!